# Java and HashMap - how to add to existing values?

Tags: java, hashmap, client-server

I am currently working on a client/server application, and I am using a HashMap to identify each client.  The client passes in two values to the server - `id` and `x`.  I am using `id` as my key, and for each element in the HashMap, I would like to use the value of `x` to add to the value the specific element with the matching key `id`.

I have the following code:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> clients = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

int x;
sock = serv.accept();
in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
in2 = sock.getInputStream();
out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

int id = in2.read();
System.out.println("id = " + id);
Object o = in.readObject();         
System.out.println("Server received " + o);
if (o instanceof Integer) {
    x = ((Integer) o).intValue();
    clients.put(id, 0 + x); //doesn't work, I need to be able to add to the existing value instead of overwriting the value

} else if (o instanceof String) {
    clients.put(id, 0);
}
out.writeObject(clients.get(id));
out.flush();
```

Could anyone help me here?

Comment: by add you mean addition in math context or you want to add one more value mapped with that key

Comment: I mean in the math context.  For example, if the client passes 1 and 3 the first time, the server should return 3.  If the client passes 1 and 5 the second time, the server should return 8.  However, if the client passes 2 and 7, the server should return 7, since 2 is a different id from 1.

Comment: In any modern form of Java (8+), `merge()` is the command specifically created for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Integer previousValue = clients.get(id);
if(previousValue == null) previousValue = 0;
clients.put(id, previousValue + x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to read value from map then you can add it something like

```
Integer resultantValue = x;
Integer previousValue = clents.get(id);
if(previousValue!=null){
  resultantValue+=previousValue;
}

clients.put(id, resultantValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 or above you can use Merge.

```
int newValue = 3;
clients.merge(id, newValue, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Integer value = new Integer(0);

if (clients.containsKey(id)) {
    value = clients.get(id);        
}
value.add(new Integer(x) + value);
clients.put(id, value);
```

Comment: I don't mean to add two elements, but to add to the value in terms of the math context.

Comment: I have modified the answer as per your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to create an extension of HashMap specifically for integers with a method specifically for adding to a particular value in the manner you specified, like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class IntegerHashMap extends HashMap<Integer,Integer>{

    public void addValueToKey(Integer key, Integer valueToAdd){
        Integer originalValue = this.get(key);
        Integer newValue = originalValue + valueToAdd;
        this.put(key, newValue);
    }

}
```

This will make it easy to use the code again if needed, which by the looks of it, it very well could be, and has the added benefit of working only with a HashMap of the correct type.

Comment: Better to override `HashMap#put`.

Comment: @Prince I considered that, but the function has a different use than `put()`, and I thought `put()` might still be necessary.